# Scrolling to the end of UITextView's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have some contents in a view (such as images, labels) and the last item is a description (`UITextView`). Now I am trying to scroll the contents dynamically based on `UITextView` text. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    _descriptions.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [_descriptions sizeToFit];

    _infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.width,
                                             _contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.height + _descriptions.frame.size.height);
}
```

Here is the result:

As you can see, there is lots of empty space. I need to scroll to the end of text.

Comment: `_descriptions.text.length` - hm, you use text length to measure height?

Comment: Because text inputs are dynamic . Yes ! I am I doing right ? @schmidt9

Comment: if `_descriptions` is your text field, then you should measure like that, I think: `_infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.width, _contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.height + _descriptions.frame.size.height);` _after_ you call `[_descriptions sizeToFit];`

Comment: @schmidt9 Thanks , it's better now,but still there is some empty space ! (less than before)

Comment: Do you call `sizeToFit` before?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is being called _after_ `viewDidLoad` as far as I know. Maybe you shuld place your measuring code in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @schmidt9 I add `-200` and it seems works fine ! here is full code :`_infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.width, _contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.height + _descriptions.frame.size.height - 200);`

Comment: hm, maybe you missed some other controls out of measuring, where are this `-200` from?

Comment: @schmidt9 I have no idea :-D but it works !

Comment: I'm glad, not to forget to vote me up ;)

Comment: It's not clear what your desired result is, and it sounds like you have a hacky (yet working) solution from the comments. Could you update the question with what it looks like in this hacky-yet-better solution, and/or better explain what is wrong with your screenshot above.

Comment: @Stonz2 I need setup something like Sky Guide application , when you touch info button, the scrolling is dynamically equal to descriptions.

Comment: @Mc.Lover could you provide screenshot with some description what you exactly want to implement.

Comment: try this code CGSize textViewSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    self.myTextView.height = textViewSize.height;

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just found the answer,in the UI there is line that separates descriptions with the some infos ! I just calculate the line's `y` and sum up with the descriptions `height` :

```
_descriptions.scrollEnabled = NO;
[_descriptions sizeToFit];
_infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_infoView.frame.size.width, _line.frame.origin.y + _descriptions.bounds.size.height);
```

now it works fine !

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you to try this.

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([myTextView.text length], 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write you code in

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {}
```

In this method,All components have frame according to running device size. and execute before appear the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
//may be it will work for you
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    //set the line break mode
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: description.font,
                              NSFontAttributeName,
                              paragraphStyle,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                              nil];


    CGRect rect = [description.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(description.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:attrDict
                                                  context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
   _infoScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_contentsOnInfoView.frame.size.width,description.frame.origin.y + size.height + 20)
```